# How do Elan Resilience, Aberrant Manifesting, and Overchannel Damage interact?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

If I apply [*Overchannel*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/overchannel-psionic/) to a power, can I use my [*Elan Resilience*](http://marksworld.zeemer.com/files/feats/featlibrary/elanresilience.html) to absorb the damage? If so, can I use the temporary power points from [*Aberrant Manifesting*](http://dsp-d20-srd.wikidot.com/elan-psion) to fuel my Resilience? On a side note, can I apply both *Overchannel* and [*Improved Overchannel*](http://www.dan-site.com/Epic_Feats.htm) to the same power?

Comment: The part about Overchannel and Improved Overchannel probably needs to be split into its own question, as it's not closely related to the part about Overchannel, Elan Resilience, and Aberrant Manifesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers to all your questions appear to be “yes,” at least, they could be yes.

- Elan resilience is extremely broadly-worded and non-specific as to what sort of damage it works on, so yes, it seems like it could work on Overchannel’s damage.
- Aberrant manifesting works on resilience; no particular reason why it wouldn’t in this case.
- Improved Overchannel, while clearly an attempt to be an extension of Overchannel, doesn’t describe its *benefit* as an improvement to the usual Overchannel benefit, it just provides a similar benefit. Therefore, you could, RAW anyway, use Improved Overchannel to double your manifester level, and then use Overchannel to bump it up a further three—nothing says they are the same source (where if Improved Overchannel said something like “you can use Overchannel to go up to twice your manifester level” or something, they wouldn’t stack). However, this is almost-certainly an oversight.

Comment: If Improved Overchannel and Overchannel are separate feats, could you use Improved Overchannel with a Wild Surge?

Comment: @Cellheim That is harder to say.